# Linear Regresion with PyTorch gives NaN values

Tags: python, pytorch, linear-regression, nan, gradient-descent

I'm learning regression (`Profit` vs `R&D`) with PyTorch. I have created the following script:

```
url =https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LakshmiPanguluri/Linear_Multiple_Regression/master/50_Startups.csv
starup = pd.read_csv(url)

profit = np.array(starup['Profit']).reshape(-1,1)
rd = np.array(starup['R&D Spend']).reshape(-1,1)
marketing = np.array(starup['Marketing Spend']).reshape(-1,1)
administration = np.array(starup['Administration']).reshape(-1,1)

profit_torch = torch.from_numpy(profit).float()
rd_torch = torch.from_numpy(rd).float().requires_grad_(True)

model = nn.Linear(1,1)
loss_function = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.010)

losses = []
iterations = 1000
for i in range(iterations):
  pred = model(rd_torch)
  loss = loss_function(pred, profit_torch)
  losses.append(loss.data)

  optimizer.zero_grad()
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()

print(loss)
plt.plot(range(iterations), losses)
tensor(nan, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)
```

My question is why it gives me a tensor with NaN values and why the loss is growing up in every iteration.

The plot of the losses is a line with a positive slope:

[image: The plot of the losses is a line with a positive slope]

[Link to the project I've been doing](https://github.com/GianCarloTG/Linear-Regression/blob/master/Linear_Regression_Profit_vs_Marketing_spend.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following changes:

Change 1: remobing `requires_grad_(True)`

```
rd_torch = torch.from_numpy(rd).float()
```

Change 2: including `model.train()` before the training loop:

```
...
model.train()
for i in range(iterations):
...
```

Change 3: using `loss.item()`

```
losses.append(loss.item())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've already solve this but for the others with the same problem. You have to calibrate the model.

Try with a large number of iterations example:

iterations=50000

and a small learning rate:

lr=0.0000010

It works for me.

Comment: can you add more detailed answers in the future?